# iOS UITextField keep keyboard on the screen

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview

I don't have the "[sender resignFirstResponder]" method called, but my keyboard still closes when the done button is pressed. I need it to stay open, even when I click done. How can I go about doing this?

Here's my action that controls the keyboard:

```
- (IBAction)returnKeyButton:(id)sender {

BOOL guessCorrect = [gameModel checkGuess:guessTextField.text];

guessTextField.text = @"";

if (guessCorrect) {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"rightAnswer", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);


    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    if (gameModel.score == 10) {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"win", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);


        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

        [self endGameWithMessage:@"You win!"];
    } else {
        scrambledWord.text = [gameModel getScrambledWord];
    }

}
remainingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.time];
playerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.score];
}
```

Comment: The point is, you guess the answer to the problem. As it stands now, I can guess the answer by using the 'return' key, but whenever I press it, the keyboard closes. It's irritating to have to press the text field again every time I want to enter an answer.

Comment: Give me a few minutes... I have an idea :)

Comment: And that's a good reason... never thought of that!

Comment: Thanks so much man! I am trying everything I can think of.

Comment: Got it! Writing an answer....

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried rearranging it many different ways as well...

Comment: See my updated answer for a link to my project.

Comment: I downloaded it, and my code is exactly like yours. They keyboard just won't stop leaving the screen. Everything compiles correctly, there are no errors either. But I'm sorry to say it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Hmm... when is returnKeyButton called?

Comment: When I click the return key button on the keyboard. But for some reason, it closes when I click it. I don't even tell it to! That's what gets me.

Comment: Hmmm... try putting [sender becomeFirstResponder]; at the end of your returnKeyButton method...

Comment: I did try it... :( I don't think there's a way around this. I guess I'm stuck with it...

Comment: Last thing... How are you calling the returnKeyButton method? As in a)  Did End on Exit b) Editing Changed c) Editing did Begin d) etc...

Comment: It doesn't matter. I've tested all of them, and not a single one will do what I need. Some of them call the functions I have in the returnKeyButton method, but the keyboard still disappears. Even with the [sender becomeFirstResponder]; method.

Comment: Hold on, maybe if I give you a picture, you can tell what exactly I am trying to do.

Comment: I was just thinking because my code only works when I have it connected to Editing Did End... Better than the picture, could you upload the Xcode Project?

Comment: Sorry, no can do, I have a really large project I plan on using for the App Store, and I don't want to risk anything. http://imgur.com/6JEfd                  When you click the button the word is guessed, and the keyboard stays up because there is no resignFirstResponder. But if I call the functions under the action linked to the keyboard, then the keyboard closes. I'm trying to eliminate the button. So when you press "Done" on the keyboard, it does the button's job.

Comment: Hmmmm..... seeing the image doesn't help me much... Sorry, bud. Hope you get it fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of... to be honest, I have never had the problem you have. I always had to use the resign call to close the keyboard or it would stay open... But, this is what I used for you:

1) Put this in the .h file:

```
-(IBAction) textFieldDoneEditing : (id) sender;
```

2) Put this in the .m file:

```
-(IBAction) textFieldDoneEditing : (id) sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [sender becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

3) Right click the UITextField in the storyboard and set the Sent Event "Editing Did End" to the textFieldDoneEditing method in the view controller.

Now, whenever the user presses "Return" or "Done", the keyboard will open and close instantaneously. Hope it helps! :)

If it doesn't work, look at my Xcode Project (which does work)... [download it here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/5um45o)